# iOS subscription trial modal

Tags: ios, subscription, trial

I am developing an update to an iOS app with a renewing subscription including a 7 day trial.

When I tap on the Free Trial button while testing my app, I see a Subscription confirmation message that says "1 year for $4.99 starting now" and no mention of the trial.

[image]

Other apps I looked at display a Trial confirmation modal that says "Free for 1 month starting now."

[image]

How do I display the Trial confirmation instead of the Subscription confirmation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not in charge of the text that is displayed in these views. Please, ensure that you specified the free trial period in subscription's introductory price page. If so, you will see the free trial message as on the second screen in the released application, just not in a Sandbox environment.